# Вызов C# функции из javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, .net, callback

У меня есть десктопное приложение на WPF, в котором лежит `<WebBrowser>`. В него грузится один сервис с сайта, для отображения и работы с картами. В зависимости от логики я через `Invoke` вызываю там разные javascript функции.

Что делать, если мне надо подписатся на callback событие? Как из javascript вызвать функцию на C#? Все что удалось нагуглить написано для использования в ASP.Net/Silverlight, но как сделать это в обычном десктоп приложении?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самое простое - сделать на С# ComVisible класс и обращаться к нему из JavaScript. Этот класс уже будет обращаться к приложению (через Application.Current).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, написал ниже более расширенный ответ.

Answer (score 6):

Что бы вызвать C# функцию из JavaScript, надо сначала установить `ObjectForScripting` (свойство `WebBrowser` класса) видимому COM-объекту:

```
[ComVisible(true)] 
public class ScriptManager 
{ 
    public ScriptManager() 
    { 
    } 

    public void MyFunc() 
    { 
         MessageBox.Show("MyFunc has been called"); 
    } 
}
```

В общем, надо создать `WebBrowser` контрол и свойству `ObjectForScripting` установить созданный `ScriptManager`, вот так:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser(); 
wb.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptManager(); 
wb.Navigate("location here");
```

Потом, в JavaScript можно вызывать созданный метод так:

```
window.external.MyFunc();
```